# Let spambots "successfully" submit form?

Tags: security, forms, spam-prevention, spamming, spam-bots

I'm about to set up my html forms so spam bots are being caught and rejected.

I wonder.. Let's say a spambot submits the form in a way that is not accepted.

Should I then let the page with the form stay as it is, displaying the error(s)?
Or should I let the page change and not showing the form?
(signalling failure/success).

If I let the spambot stay on the form page, it can easier continually submit and try with different data.

If I show the page displaying an error (maybe with error header set) but not the form anymore, how would most spambots react to that?

When would it probably try again vs. leave the site?

What is best to signal to a bot falling into traps?

Comment: WHat are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Steve Less spambot traffic. Should be obvious

Comment: Based on your question and ideas, you won't have less spam bots.  You aren't reducing the numbers.  All you are asking about is how you ought to handle them.   Two very different things.